# WCF Service not hitting from postman over https

Tags: c#, wcf

Before adding SSL certificate postman query is hitting. But when i added SSL certificate, Postman request is not working. 
I have attached file of postman request and following is my webConfig file.
It is giving Error 400 Not Found.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <section name="SmartTrack.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
          <section name="CMSWebService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SmartTrack.Properties.Settings.connectionstring" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=CommandControl2.3;User ID=sa;Password=smarti123#" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="appVersion" value="15" />
        <add key="appCode" value="1.2.3" />
        <add key="appUpdatePriority" value="1" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings />
        <client />
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="True" />
        <services>
          <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="SmartTrack.CMSWebService">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SmartTrack.ISmartTrack" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />


          </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webBehavior">
              <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />


            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Default">
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>

            </behavior>
            <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        <serviceAuthorization
          serviceAuthorizationManagerType
            =" WcfWebHttpIISHostingSample.RestAuthorizationManager, WcfWebHttpIISHostingSample"/>
      </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />

      </system.webServer>
      <applicationSettings>
        <SmartTrack.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name="SYSTEM_LOG" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="TRANSACTION_LOG" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="COMMAND_LOG" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="EXCEPTION_LOG" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="ERROR_LOG" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="CONFIG_LOGLEVEL" serializeAs="String">
            <value>0</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="CONFIG_COMPONENT" serializeAs="String">
            <value>0</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="LogPath" serializeAs="String">
            <value>C:\ServiceSmartTrack</value>
          </setting>
        </SmartTrack.Properties.Settings>
        <CMSWebService.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name="SYSTEM_LOG" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="TRANSACTION_LOG" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="COMMAND_LOG" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="EXCEPTION_LOG" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="ERROR_LOG" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="CONFIG_LOGLEVEL" serializeAs="String">
            <value>0</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="CONFIG_COMPONENT" serializeAs="String">
            <value>0</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="LogPath" serializeAs="String">
            <value>C:\ServiceSmartTrack</value>
          </setting>
        </CMSWebService.Properties.Settings>
      </applicationSettings>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Check your screen shot it is giving 404. So please check your API URL.

Comment: #Vinoth  : API URL is correct one

Comment: Then check the API name . because 404 means not found. URL which you are trying is not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the https endpoint, and then add the https protocol and specify the https certificate in IIS.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl
Here is my configuration file whose http/https endpoint are all configurated, wish it is useful to you.

```
       <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
<!--http, https are all configurated-->
          <service behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior" name="WcfService1.Service1"> <!--http, https are all configurated-->
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webbev" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"></endpoint>
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webbev" bindingConfiguration="com"></endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
          </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
          <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="mybinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
              <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
              </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="com">
              <security mode="None"></security>
            </binding>
          </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="mybehavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webbev">
              <webHttp />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
          <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />   </system.serviceModel>
```

Result.
[image]
By the way, I need to configure https/http binding base address in IIS.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

Refer following URLs you will get some idea about your issue

[How to enable HTTPS in WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784776/how-to-enable-https-in-wcf-service)

[Changing Web.Config for SSL Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887990/changing-web-config-for-ssl-website)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl