# WCF not working when ssl is applied to website

Tags: wcf, web-config

I have applied ssl to my domain, but after that my wcf stopped working. I tried to add `mexhttpsmapping` but it not worked for me.

I am using wcf to fetch data in json format. My web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" 
multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="restLargeBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
transferMode="Streamed">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="myWebEndPointBehaviour">
      <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" 
defaultBodyStyle="Bare" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" 
helpEnabled="true"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="myServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="DemoWCFServiceForVision.Service1" 
behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" contract="DemoWCFServiceForVision.IService1" 
binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="restLargeBinding" 
behaviorConfiguration="myWebEndPointBehaviour"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" contract="DemoWCFServiceForVision.IService1" 
binding="mexHttpBinding"/>
  </service>
</services>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>

 <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
            <match url="(.*)" /> 
            <conditions> 
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
            </conditions> 
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" 
url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>   
    </rules>
</rewrite>

<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did your cat just walk over your keyboard?

Comment: Could you please give me answer...@mathyn

Comment: What do you mean with "stopped working"? Do you get any errors?

Comment: it is giving error as "Moved Permanently" and 404 And it is not returning data

Comment: Comment out rewrite rule for testing purpose and see if it works using https. Also add your client program details in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to configure transport layer security and https service endpoint on webhttpbinding. You could refer to the example in the below reply.
[WCF Service not hitting from postman over https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53761119/wcf-service-not-hitting-from-postman-over-https/53776265#53776265)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.